# error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lsb_release' when trying to run lsb_release -a

Tags: linux, debian, python, apt

Seeing the following output when trying to run lsb_release on Debian:

```
(venv) vm-1671541226:/$ lsb_release -a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/lsb_release", line 25, in <module>
    import lsb_release
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lsb_release'
```

Debian version: 10.12
Python version: 3.9.14

According to apt-get it is there:

```
(venv) vm-1671541226:/$ sudo apt-get install lsb-release
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
lsb-release is already the newest version (10.2019051400).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  fonts-dejavu libyelp0 python-apt-common python3-apt python3-distro-info yelp-xsl
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 187 not upgraded.
```

I then tried reinstalling it but still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The solution explained in [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44967202/pip-is-showing-error-lsb-release-a-returned-non-zero-exit-status-1), could help you to solve the issue:

> you may just need to use a specific version of Python 3